# Android making CardViews programmatically

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create **CardView** type objects which will enable users to input their working hours for each day. I first did them in plain xml, which worked flawlessly, but not once I had to make some small changes and that meant modifying the code in 8 places.

I managed to understand how to create the cardviews programmatically ( I am using an **enum** type class in order to hold id's and names for the elements from the cardviews. The problem is, the result doesn't work as it should.
I can't manage to make the elements( **CheckBox, TextView, SpinnerStart, SpinnerEnd**) to be in the right place.

`_checkBox` should be aligned to the start of `_relativeLayoutInCard`, `_TVDayLabel` after it, then `_spinnerEnd` aligned to the end of the relatie layout and `_spinnerStart` at the beginning of `spinnerEnd`

**The problem seems to be at the `_layoutParamsOtherViews`**

```
private void createCards() {
    /* get each day from enum and make the card
     *  with the necessary elements
     */
    DaysOfWeek _previousDay = DaysOfWeek.MONDAY;
    RelativeLayout _rootRelativeLayout = mActivity.findViewById(R.id.act_SWHours_RL_RootCV);

    for (DaysOfWeek _day : DaysOfWeek.values()) {
        Log.d("Stop", _day.geteDisplayName());
        CardView _cardview = new CardView(mActivity, null, R.style.CardViewSWHours);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams _layoutParamsCV = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        );
        /* for Checkbox, Textviews and spinners inside CV */
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams _layoutParamsOtherViews =  new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        );

        RelativeLayout _relativeLayoutInCard = new RelativeLayout(mActivity, null, R.style.RelativeLayoutInCVSWHours);
        _relativeLayoutInCard.setLayoutParams(_layoutParamsCV);

        if(_day.geteDisplayName().equals("Monday") || _day.geteDisplayName().equals("All week days")) {
            Log.d("Stop", "It gets here");
            _layoutParamsCV.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.act_SWHours_CB_DiffHours);
        }
        else {
            _layoutParamsCV.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, _previousDay.getCardViewId());
        }

        if(_day.geteDisplayName().equals("Saturday")) {
            _layoutParamsCV.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, DaysOfWeek.ALLDAYS.getCardViewId());
        }

        _layoutParamsCV.setMargins(64, 9, 64, 9);
        _cardview.setRadius(32);
        _cardview.setCardElevation(6);
        _cardview.setId(_day.getCardViewId());
        _cardview.setLayoutParams(_layoutParamsCV);

        _rootRelativeLayout.addView(_cardview);
        _cardview.addView(_relativeLayoutInCard);


        CheckBox _checkBox = new CheckBox(mActivity);
        _checkBox.setId(_day.geteCheckBoxID());
        _checkBox.setText(R.string.act_SWHours_CB_FreeDay);
        _relativeLayoutInCard.addView(_checkBox, _layoutParamsOtherViews);
        _layoutParamsOtherViews.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_START);
        _checkBox.setLayoutParams(_layoutParamsOtherViews);
        _layoutParamsOtherViews.removeRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_START);

        TextView _TVDayLabel = new TextView(mActivity);
        _TVDayLabel.setText(_day.geteDisplayName());
        _relativeLayoutInCard.addView(_TVDayLabel, _layoutParamsOtherViews);
        _layoutParamsOtherViews.addRule(RelativeLayout.END_OF, _day.geteCheckBoxID());
        _TVDayLabel.setLayoutParams(_layoutParamsOtherViews);
        _layoutParamsOtherViews.removeRule(RelativeLayout.END_OF);

        Spinner _spinnerEnd = new Spinner(mActivity);
        _spinnerEnd.setId(_day.geteSpinnerEndID());
        _relativeLayoutInCard.addView(_spinnerEnd, _layoutParamsOtherViews);
        _layoutParamsOtherViews.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_END);
        _spinnerEnd.setLayoutParams(_layoutParamsOtherViews);
        _layoutParamsOtherViews.removeRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_END);

        Spinner _spinnerStart = new Spinner(mActivity);
        _spinnerStart.setId(_day.geteSpinnerStartID());
        _relativeLayoutInCard.addView(_spinnerStart, _layoutParamsOtherViews);
        _layoutParamsOtherViews.addRule(RelativeLayout.START_OF, _day.geteSpinnerEndID());
        _spinnerStart.setLayoutParams(_layoutParamsOtherViews);

        _previousDay = _day;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the problem was that I used the same `LayoutParams` object at all views( even though I removed the rules before assigning it to the next one).

In order for this to work, just other `LayoutParams` objects for each view and that shall do the work.

```
/* for Checkbox, Textviews and spinners inside CV */
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams _layoutParamsCB =  new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        );
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams _layoutParamsTV =  new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        );
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams _layoutParamsSPS =  new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        );
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams _layoutParamsSPE =  new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        );

        ...
        TextView _TVDayLabel = new TextView(mActivity);
        _TVDayLabel.setText(_day.geteDisplayName());
        _relativeLayoutInCard.addView(_TVDayLabel, _layoutParamsTV);
        _layoutParamsTV.addRule(RelativeLayout.END_OF, _day.geteCheckBoxID());
        _TVDayLabel.setLayoutParams(_layoutParamsTV);
```